# Ruby on Rails ajax pop up messages

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ajax, css

I'm using bootstrap in my ruby on rails application. I sometimes show messages to users by using pop-up. I created following css and html lines:

```
.modal-dialog {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 988888; 
  padding-top: 20px; 
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); 
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
  margin: 0px!important;
}

.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 600px;
  height: 550px;
  border-radius: 2px!important;
}
```

I want to show popup-2

```
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
       <span class="model_box_close">&times;</span>
       Popup 1
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to show popup-2

```
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div id="message-content" class="modal-content">
       <span class="model_box_close">&times;</span>
       Popup 2
    </div>
</div>
```

What I want to do is create message content with ajax and append it to popup. How can I achieve that.

In ruby on rails we can execute ruby on rails ajax event like that:

```
$("<%= escape_javascript(render "popupcontent" ) %>").appendTo("#message-content");
```

I want to use my message box by clicking hyperlinks with ajax.

Any suggestions,

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have 2 routes that you can take, you can have the modal open and then fire off an Ajax request and update the content, as seen in [this](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-related-target) example from the bootstrap site

```
$('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
  var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
  var recipient = button.data('whatever') // Extract info from data-* attributes
  // If necessary, you could initiate an AJAX request here (and then do the updating in a callback).
  // Update the modal's content. We'll use jQuery here, but you could use a data binding library or other methods instead.
  var modal = $(this)
  modal.find('.modal-title').text('New message to ' + recipient)
  modal.find('.modal-body input').val(recipient)
})
```

or, if you want to click a link and send of an Ajax request and upon completion of the request show a modal you could use [.modal('show')](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modal-show) after updating the contents in your Ajax callback.

```
$("a[data-remote]").on("ajax:success", function() {
  $('#myModal').modal('show')
})
```